# Blacklist bots from websites

Tags: bots, blacklist

I signed up for an API. Its documentation says: "It is recommended that you blacklist bots from your websites to reduce usage costs."

What does that mean and how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to set up a robots.txt file that gives instructions on what bots are and aren't allowed to do.

See http://www.robotstxt.org/.

Comment: Generally compliant robots follow robots.txt but it wouldn't hurt to also implement meta-tags.  Some say overkill, I say if you are using templates, why not.  Additional reading, not to replace answer, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard.